# remove value from form within component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to let users remove values from there current settings.

I have a series of values users can have for there settings that are displayed in a pill format that they can click X on to delete, i.e.,

```
export default function Pill({ value, handleChange }) {

  // const [times, setTimes] = useState([]);

    return (
      <div className="bg-gray-600 text-white text-xs px-2 py-0.5 w-max-content rounded-lg align-middle mr-1 mb-1">
        {value}
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          width="16"
          height="16"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          fill="none"
          stroke="currentColor"
          strokeWidth="2"
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeLinejoin="round"
          className="inline-block align-middle cursor-pointer"
          onClick={() => handleChange(value, "remove")}
        >
          <line x1="18" y1="6" x2="6" y2="18" />
          <line x1="6" y1="6" x2="18" y2="18" />
        </svg>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

This is used as a component as below,

```
{substanceDetails &&
              substanceDetails.map((subst) => (
                <Pill
                  registerInput={register}
                  optionLabel="substance"
                  value={subst.substance}
                  key={subst.substance}
                  optionName="substance"
                  allOptions={["Dexamphetamine", "Ritalin"]}
                  handleChange={handleChange}
                />
              ))}
```

Given the handle change, which needs to be changed, but it would look something like this,

```
const handleChange = (value, mode) => {
    let updatedValues = values;
    if (mode === 'remove') {
      updatedValues = values.filter((elem) => elem !== value);
    } else if (!updatedValues.includes(value)) updatedValues = [...values, value];
    setValues(updatedvalues);
  };
```

Comment: Is the `values` an array or an object?

Comment: It's an array, so multiple

Answer (score 2):

#### Mutation issue

You are mutating state in your `handleChange` function:

```
const handleChange = (value, mode) => {
    let updatedValues = values; //takes the reference to state variable
    if (mode === 'remove') {
      updatedValues = values.filter((elem) => elem !== value); //mutation
    } else if (!updatedValues.includes(value)) updatedValues = [...values, value];
    setValues(updatedvalues);
  };
```

You can use something like this:

```
const handleChange = (value, mode) => {
    if(mode==="remove") setValues(vals => vals.includes(value) ? vals.filter(v => v !== value) : [...vals, value])
  };
```

### If it is an array of objects:

`.includes()` won't work as expected if your array elements are not primitive values. You can use `.find()` or `.some()` in that case:

*Example of filtering by the field `duration` for simplicity*:

```
const handleChange = (value, mode) => {
    if(mode==="remove") setValues(vals => vals.find(v=> v.duration === value.duration) ? vals.filter(v => v.duration !== value.duration) : [...vals, value])
  };
```

Comment: Still not working saddly eh

Comment: Provide a reproducible code, and I can help more.

Comment: KK one sec man, i'll put it into a notepad

Comment: If you can provide a `codesandbox` that would be perfect. Also _not working_ is not descriptive enough sadly.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/m1YfWZbb

Comment: This is the code completely,

Comment: You are trying to `setValue` inside `handleChange`, which is not an array. Don't you want to `handleChange` on `values` which is an array?

Comment: Yeah! That makes sense. Will that mean that the value will change, and therefore the value in state will change as well? i.e., substanceDetails

Comment: In your question, your `handleChange` function solely modifies the `values` array. That is the one you need to replace. Since `values` is a state variable, a change will be reflected, causing a re-render, and your child will be removed from the array.

Comment: okay awesome. The issue is that values isn't held in the parent component, there's a value in the pill component, the only input to the form is the substanceDetails array

Comment: I'm thinking, maybe in the handle change I can make it so that it takes the value, removes the pill, then it also finds the specific key and value and removes that

Comment: made a change that looks a bit more positive

Comment: IMHO, handleChange doesn't actually mutate the state.
A simplified version of the code would be (you can copy paste into a browser console):
`const values = ['a', 'b'];
let updatedValues = values;
updatedValues = values.filter(value => value === 'b');

console.log({ updatedValues, values });`
This would produce ['b'] for updatedValues and original values would be ['a', 'b']

Comment: For clarity, `.filter` does *not* mutate the array. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 2):

After reading your code, I found the main problem might not be the mutation issue, but you didn't manage the state very well.

First, your `substanceDetails` should be stored in `YourSubstanceListComponent` component, not in your `Pill` component, something like this. **This is the main reason why your first approach does not work**.

```
// in YourSubstanceListComponent
const YourSubstanceListComponent = () = {
  const [values, setValues] = useState([]);
  const handleChange = (value, mode,optionName) => {
    // Should call `setValues` in this function
    const newValues = [];// TODO
    setValues(newValues);
  }

  return (
    <>
      {values.map(v => <Pill {...otherPillProps} value={v.substance} />)}
    </>
  )
}
```

Then, your `handleChange` should be placed in `YourSubstanceListComponent`. The reason why is you might don't want to pass `setValues` to your `Pill` component.

Next is the part about getting new removed values items. According the docs:

- [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
- [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

They don't modify the original array. So you can use them like in your code and it should work.

But, I found some more problems in your code and I think you should check it again.

- [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) will return your array to a single value. I saw that you used it to get a new array from an array. It makes no sense since you can use `map` (when the number of elements does not change) or `filter` (when the number of elements will change). I rarely use any other methods apart from `map` and `filter` in all my life.
- In your updated `handleChange` function, I don't see the `optionName` variable. Where does it come from? Maybe you didn't update your `Pill` component.